# Centering Dropdown

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm currently learning css and attempting to center the code found here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar

I've tried a combination of inline-block and text-align: center, but am unable to center it so "Home", "News", "Dropdown", and "Link" are centered instead of floating towards the left.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you and hopefully you had a restful weekend!

Comment: Not sure how someone can figure out  what you're doing wrong: You didn't include any css code or a picture of the output you're getting.

Comment: The css code is in the link. I'm working through an online example but trying to get the links centered

Comment: Nobody should have to click a link to see your code. Edit and put it in your question, along with your output.

Comment: People use jsfiddle all the time. That is a link, is it not? This link has the same functionality as jsfiddle giving both the input code and output code.

Comment: @MMM people should NOT use jsfiddle/codepen alone. They can include a link if they also include the code in their post, but a post with no code and a link to jsfiddle/codepen is frowned upon here. If they do that, we'll comment in this same way to them. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]"*

Comment: I see, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Elements have a float:left property you cannot center them, need to change the css as per needs

Try this new CSS

CSS

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align:center;

}

.container a {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
   display:inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```